# Setting a range to have a Macro run on all populated rows in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I've pieced together a macro to allow me to calculate the cost of a story task by calculating the specific rate based on the developer assigned.  I have the rate table on a second sheet.  I am able to get a result for the cell that the macro is set to (Row 2), but want it to run on all rows.  I know I have to set a generic range, but am not sure.  How should I change the range declare to run on all rows?
Here is the code:

```
Sub GetCost()
  Range("D2").Select
  ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Dim Estimate As Integer, Assignee As String, RodRate As Integer, GarthRate As Integer, DerekRate As Integer, TotalCost As Integer

    Estimate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value
    Assignee = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value
    RodRate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
    GarthRate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").Value
    DerekRate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Value

    If Assignee = "Rod" Then
        TotalCost = Estimate * RodRate
    ElseIf Assignee = "Garth" Then
        TotalCost = Estimate * GarthRate
    ElseIf Assignee = "Derek" Then
        TotalCost = Estimate * DerekRate
    Else
        TotalCost = "0"

    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Formula = TotalCost
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have rewritten your code with explanations which I hope are enough for you to understand why.  There is much more that I could say.  I hope this is a good balance between too little and too much.

However, I have to point out that there are some excellent project management tools available.  I do not believe this is a good use of your time.

**Random points**

On 32-bit computers, Long is better than Integer.

Do not declare your variables inside a loop.  The scope of a variable declared inside a sub-routine is the
the sub-routine so declare them at the top of the sub-routine.

You can declare all your variables in a single `Dim` statement but I find it confusing unless there is a real association between two or more variable.  I might have:

```
Dim RodRate As Long, GarthRate As Long, DerekRate As Long
```

because these variables are associated.  However the trouble with this approach is that you will have to add `MaryRate` and `JohnRate` and `AngelaRate` when these people join your project.

You need an array:

```
Dim PersonRate(1 To 3) As Long
```

where `PersonRate(1)` = Rate for Rod, `PersonRate(2)` = Rate for Garth and `PersonRate(3)` = Rate for Derek.

But this is hardly any better. You want a table that can grow.  So today:

```
   Name   Rate
   Rod    20
   Garth  25
   Derek  15
```

Next week:

```
   Name   Rate
   Rod    20
   Garth  25
   Derek  15
   Mary   30
```

With this, you pick up the Assignee's name, run down the table until you find their name then look across for their rate.

I assume you have a table like this in Sheet2.  You could keep going back to Sheet2 but better to load the table into an array.

We could have:

```
Dim PersonName() As String
Dim PersonRate() As Long
```

so `PersonRate(2)` gives the rate for `PersonName(2)`.

Note in my first array declaration I wrote: `PersonRate(1 To 3)`.  This time, the brackets are empty.  With `PersonRate(1 To 3)`, I am saying I want exactly three entries in the array and this cannot be changed.  With `PersonRate()`, I am saying I want an array but I will not know how many entries until run time.

I said we could have two arrays, `PersonName()` and `PersonRate()` and this is what I have done.  This is an easy-to-understand approach but I do not think it is the best approach.  I prefer structures.  When you have got this macro working and before you start your next look up `User Types` which is the VBA name for a structure.

Consider:

```
   With Sheets("Sheet2")
     RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With
```

There is a lot to explain here.

`Cells` means I want to address a cell within the active workbook. `.Cells` means I want to address a cell within the sheet identified in the With statement.  This means I do not have to select Sheet1 or Sheet2 to look at their contents.  Selecting worksheets is slow and the code tends to be more difficult to understand.

`.Cells(Row, Column)` identifies a cell.  Row must be a number but column can be a number or a column code: A=1, B=2, Z=26, AA=27, etc.

`Rows.Count` returns the number of rows in a sheet for the version of Excel you are using.  So `.Cells(Rows.Count, "A")` identifies the bottom of column "A".

`End(xlUp)` is the VBA equivalent of clicking `Ctrl`+`UpArrow`. If you are not familar with `Ctrl`+`Arrow` I suggest you play with these four controls.  Note, these controls give easy to understand results with a rectangular table.  However, if there are empty cells, the results can be strange.

Putting this together: `.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` means start at the bottom of column A, go up until you hit a cell with a value and return its row number.  So this sets `RowMax` to the last row of the Rate table.  When you add row 5 with Mary's name and rate, this code will automatically adjust.

**Revised code**

This should be enough to get you started.  Welcome to the joys of programming.

```
' * Require all variables to be declared which means a misspelt name
'   is not taken as an implicit declaration
Option Explicit

Sub GetCost()

   Dim Estimate As Integer
   Dim Assignee As String
   Dim TotalCost As Integer

   Dim PersonName() As String
   Dim PersonRate() As String
   Dim InxPerson As Long

   Dim RowCrnt As Long
   Dim RowMax As Long

   ' You can declare constants and use them in place of literals.
   ' You will see why later.  I could have made these strings and
   ' used "A", "B", "D", "E" and "F" as the values.  Change if that
   ' is easier for you.
   Const ColS2Name As Long = 1
   Const ColS2Rate As Long = 2
   Const ColS1Estimate As Long = 4
   Const ColS1Assignee As Long = 5
   Const ColS1Total As Long = 6

   ' Before doing anything else we must load PersonName and PersonRate from
   ' Sheet2.  I assume the structure of Sheet2 is:

   '     A      B
   '  1  Name   Rate
   '  2  Rod    20
   '  3  Garth  25
   '  4  Derek  15

   With Sheets("Sheet2")

     RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColS2Name).End(xlUp).Row

     ' I now know how big I want the the name and rate arrays to be
     ReDim PersonName(1 To RowMax - 1)
     ReDim PersonRate(1 To RowMax - 1)

     ' Load these arrays
     For RowCrnt = 2 To RowMax
       ' I could have used 1 and 2 or "A" and "B" for the column 
       ' but this is easier to understand particularly if you come
       ' back to this macro in six month's time.
       PersonName(RowCrnt - 1) = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColS2Name).Value
       PersonRate(RowCrnt - 1) = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColS2Rate).Value
     Next
   End With

   With Sheets("Sheet1")

     ' I am using the same variable for rows in sheets Sheet1 and Sheet2.
     ' This is OK because I never look at Sheet1 and Sheet2 at the same time.
     RowCrnt = 2

     Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColS1Estimate))
       Estimate = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColS1Estimate).Value
       Assignee = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColS1Assignee).Value
       .Cells(RowCrnt, ColS1Total).Value = 0
       ' Locate the Assignee in the PersonName array and
       ' extract the matching rate
       For InxPerson = 1 To UBound(PersonName)
         If PersonName(InxPerson) = Assignee Then
           .Cells(RowCrnt, ColS1Total).Value = Estimate * PersonRate(InxPerson)
           Exit For
         End If
       Next
       RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
     Loop
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tony, Thanks for the information and the re-write.  I really appreciate the explanation of how to make this do what I wanted.  I'll study it and learn how it's doing it and go forward from there!

Answer (score 1):

Tony's answer is a great solution and introduction to programming and very well written so I've +1 it. However unless I'm missing something code should always be the last resort in excel as it is very slow compared to formulas, I would have thought that a simple lookup would suffice, something like:

```
=D2*(vlookup(E2,'sheet2'!A:B,2,FALSE))
```

Copied down the column

Comment: Thanks for the +1.  I agree that a formula will solve Stoney's immediate problem but I assumed this was the first step towards something more complex.

Comment: Kyle, You are right.  This is more of a proof of concept for me and a challenge to see if I could program what I wanted.  I also am working on understanding how it all works...